# How to find location of Pandas installed on Windows

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am looking to review the source code for Pandas and cannot seem to find it on my computer using a simple system search.  I installed the package through Anaconda.  Is there a common place that libraries installed through Anaconda are located, or is there a script I can run in Terminal to provide the location of where it is installed?

Comment: Look at `pandas.__path__`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 14):

You can find the location by looking at

```
import pandas
pandas.__path__
```